# unknown error when making a http request to open weather api

Tags: angular, stackblitz

i making a http call in my stckblitz project

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + data.city + '&appid=' + this.APIKey
```

but it always gives an error

```
Http failure response for http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=6492527f849e5034d485df6b5981d407: 0 Unknown Error
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-weather-app

Comment: try this format https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=<ur_apikey>&q=Hobart&units=imperial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `https` version of the url:

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + data.city + '&appid=' + this.APIKey`